# How can I mark a read message in gnus as “unread”?

Tags: emacs, gnus

This is a simple question, but I did not find an answer:

How can I change a read message to "unread" and how can I toggle the read state of a message?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can clear its mark by <kbd>M</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> or <kbd>M-u</kbd>.

Answer (score 8):

Here's how to find the answer:

- <kbd>C-h</kbd> <kbd>i</kbd> - open Info
- <kbd>m</kbd> `gnus` <kbd>RET</kbd> - open the Gnus manual
- <kbd>i</kbd> `mark as unread` <kbd>RET</kbd> - look up "mark as unread" in the index

This gives you:

```
`M c'
`M-u'
     Clear all readedness-marks from the current article
     (`gnus-summary-clear-mark-forward').  In other words, mark the
     article as unread.
```

Though you have the correct answer already, I just wanted to grab the opportunity to show that the Gnus manual is actually quite easy to access.

Comment: Thanks - but the strange thing is: I do not have the gnus manual there? Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you by any chance using Emacs from Debian packages? Debian considers the GNU Free Documentation License (GFDL) non-free in certain cases, so the Emacs documentation is in the [emacs23-common-non-dfsg](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/emacs23-common-non-dfsg) package in the `non-free` section.

Comment: Spot on - I am using ubuntu and emacs24 and there is the dfsg package. Installed and there it is - thanks